# Print linkedlist reversely

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, linked-list

I'm working on the problem of print a linked list reversely without destruction. My specific questions are,

1. wondering if any other better ideas, space complexity improvement, my current space complexity is `O(n)` using recursive call stack;
2. wondering any ideas to improve algorithm time complexity?

BTW: If there are anything wrong with my current code, like logical bugs, please feel free to advise.

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, nextNode):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = nextNode
    def print_reverse(self):
        if not self.nextNode:
            print self.value
            return
        else:
            self.nextNode.print_reverse()
            print self.value
if __name__ == "__main__":
    head = LinkedListNode('a', LinkedListNode('b', LinkedListNode('c', LinkedListNode('d', None))))
    head.print_reverse()
```

Comment: for a one direction liked list this is the best complexity you can get. you could make a double linked list (one pointer to the previous node) and you would have `O(1)` for memory complexity

Answer (score 2):

Your `print_reverse()` can be simplified to:

```
def print_reverse(self):
    if self.nextNode:
        self.nextNode.print_reverse()
    print(self.value)
```

I don't see how you can improve this, you will need a stack of some description because this list is not doubly linked. But you can use your own stack, which would avoid the risk of recursion overflow:

```
def print_reverse(self):
    stack = [self]
    nextNode = self.nextNode
    while nextNode:
        stack.append(nextNode)
        nextNode = nextNode.nextNode
    while stack:
        print(stack.pop().value)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `LinkedListNode`'s are not immutable and you are only concerned about the final structure of the linked list, you can reverse the linked list in one iteration, and print the elements while re-reversing it from the end in another iteration; which gives you `Ө(1)` space complexity and `Ө(n)` time complexity.

Otherwise, if you are not allowed to change any structure at any point, I think `Ө(n)` space is the best you can get.

---

Here is a Java implementation:

```
class LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    LinkedListNode next;
    LinkedListNode(int data) { this.data = data; }
}

class LinkedListReversePrintImplementation {
    static void printReversely(LinkedListNode node) {
        LinkedListNode currNode = node,
                       nextNode = node.next,
                       temp;

        // Remove the link from first node
        currNode.next = null;

        // Reverse the other links
        while (nextNode != null) {
            temp = nextNode.next;
            nextNode.next = currNode;
            currNode = nextNode;
            nextNode = temp;
        }

        // `currNode` now contains the last node
        // Initialize the `nextNode` of the reversed linked list
        nextNode = currNode.next;

        // Remove the first link again
        currNode.next = null;

        // Print the last node
        System.out.println(currNode.data);

        // Print the other nodes while re-reversing it
        while (nextNode != null) {
            System.out.println(nextNode.data);

            temp = nextNode.next;
            nextNode.next = currNode;
            currNode = nextNode;
            nextNode = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Confused, how is this `O(1)` space complexity? Wouldn't you need to assemble the whole list in reverse?

Comment: @AChampion It approaches `O(1)` because you only need to store the two values you are swapping: `node1.next = None, node2.next = node1, node3.next = node2`. It's definitely constant space complexity.

Comment: @Aaron3468 Actually it doesn't approach `O(1)`, it's in fact `O(1)` since it's an asymptotic analysis.

Comment: @SamedDüzçay I avoid making absolute statements on this site without having a strong source to link. Pedantry is very common here, but at least it helps validate my understandings.

Comment: @AChampion If we are talking about time complexity; both are `O(n)`, or better than that, `Θ(n)` since we know the lower bound too. About space complexity; this solution is `Θ(1)`, while the OP's solution is `Θ(n)`. If you have any trouble with Big-Omega or Big-Theta, you can take a look at here: https://cathyatseneca.gitbooks.io/data-structures-and-algorithms/content/analysis/notations.html

Answer (score 0):

Using O(n) space to print the list in reverse is not very nice, especially if that's stack space.

If you can't modify the list, then you can do it in O(log N) space and O(N log N) time like this:

```
class LinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, value, nextNode):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = nextNode

def count(list):
    ret=0
    while list:
        ret+=1
        list=list.nextNode
    return ret

def print_reverse(list,size=-1):
    if size<0 and list:
        size=count(list)

    while size>1:
        midpoint=size/2
        tail=list
        for _ in xrange(midpoint):
            tail=tail.nextNode
        print_reverse(tail,size-midpoint)
        size=midpoint
    if size>0:
        print list.value


head = tail = LinkedListNode(1,None)
for n in range(2,29):
    tail.nextNode=LinkedListNode(n,None)
    tail=tail.nextNode

print_reverse(head)
```